# Input field "placeholder" not working/showing

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js, express

I'm a newbie front-end dev, I'm having trouble understanding why the placeholder is not working, I tried using LABEL tag but it won't disappear as I start typing into the text input. I am serving the HTML with express to heroku.
here's the code:

```
          <!-- <label for="firstname">FirstName</label> -->
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="firstName" name="firstname" placeholder="FirstName" required autofocus/>
        </div>
        <div class="form-floating">
          <!-- <label for="lastname">LastName</label> -->
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="lastName" name="lastname" placeholder="LastName" required/>
        </div>
        <div class="form-floating">
          <!-- <label for="email">example@gmail.com</label> -->
          <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" placeholder="example@gmail.com" required/>
        </div>
        <button class="w-100 btn btn-lg btn-primary" type="submit">
          Sign Up
        </button>
        <p class="mt-5 mb-3 text-muted">&copy; Example Inc.</p>
```

edit:
I am using bootstrap for styling and Express and NodeJs for serving files to the frontend.
here is the overall code for signup page:

```
<link href="../css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  </head>
  <body class="text-center">
    <main class="form-signin">
      <form method="post" action="/">
        <img
          class="mb-4"
          src="../images/example.png"
          alt=""
          width="72"
          height="57"
        />
        <h1 class="h3 mb-3 fw-normal">Sign up to my newsletter</h1>

        <div class="form-floating">
          <!-- <label for="firstname">FirstName</label> -->
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="firstName" name="firstname" placeholder="FirstName" required autofocus/>
        </div>
        <div class="form-floating">
          <!-- <label for="lastname">LastName</label> -->
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="lastName" name="lastname" placeholder="LastName" required/>
        </div>
        <div class="form-floating">
          <!-- <label for="email">example@gmail.com</label> -->
          <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" placeholder="example@gmail.com" required/>
        </div>
        <button class="w-100 btn btn-lg btn-primary" type="submit">
          Sign Up
        </button>
        <p class="mt-5 mb-3 text-muted">&copy; Example Inc.</p>
      </form>
    </main>
  </body>
```

and minimal styling used in stylesheet:

```
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  padding-top: 40px;
  padding-bottom: 40px;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
}

.form-signin {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 330px;
  padding: 15px;
  margin: auto;
}


.form-signin .form-floating:focus-within {
  z-index: 2;
}

.form-signin #firstName {
  margin-bottom: -1px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 0;

}
.form-signin #lastName {
  margin-bottom: -1px;
  border-top-left-radius: 0;
  border-top-right-radius: 0;
}

.form-signin input[type="email"] {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  border-top-left-radius: 0;
  border-top-right-radius: 0;
}
```

This is how it is displayed on the web app

[image]

Comment: See https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/forms/floating-labels/

Answer (score 1):

As Phil said in the comment to your post the issue is that you're using Bootstrap [Floating Labels](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/forms/floating-labels/) (by wrapping your inputs with a .form-floating) but you're not supplying labels (yours are commented out).

```
<div class="form-floating">
    <label for="firstname">FirstName</label>
    <input 
        type="text"
        class="form-control"
        id="firstName" 
        name="firstname" 
        placeholder="FirstName" 
        required 
        autofocus/>
</div>
```

Alternatively you can remove the .form-floating surrounding div and use the placeholders as normal

```
<div>
    <label for="firstname">FirstName</label>
    <input 
        type="text"
        class="form-control"
        id="firstName" 
        name="firstname" 
        placeholder="FirstName" 
        required 
        autofocus/>
</div>
```

Here they are uncommented and working correctly: [on codepen](https://codepen.io/danhebdon/pen/eYVgqbK)

Comment: Thank you, I commented out labels as they were also not working, after looking at the documentation, the labels were misplaced, they should go after the input tag

Answer (score -1):

Remove class **form-floating** from div tag it will work.